# Add another method to every implementation of my Interface in all implementations

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have an interface:

```
public interface InterfaceListener {
    void eventEnd();
}
```

Some methods receives this `InterfaceListener` as a parameter and every one of course implement it on his own way. For example:

```
myObject.callMethod(false,InterfaceListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventEnd() {
        //do some extra code
    }
});
```

Now I want to add some changes, to insure that every implementation in `eventEnd()` will be called only after it's passed another method - `callMyExtraMethod()` that common to all the calls, something like that:

```
myObject.callMethod(false,InterfaceListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventEnd() {
        if (callMyExtraMethod()) {
            //do some extra code
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas how can I add it to the logic without passing on every implementation and adding manually that same check to all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 7, one way to achieve this - 
Create an `AbstractListener` class with abstract methods 
`eventEnd` and `callMyExtraMethod` and a template method `templateMethod`

```
public abstract class AbstractListener {

   public abstract void eventEnd();
   public abstract boolean callMyExtraMethod();

   public void templateMethod(){
    if(callMyExtraMethod()){
        eventEnd();
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create the Anonymous classes and call the `templateMethod()`. This will ensure the `callMyExtraMethod()` check before invoking `eventEnd()`

```
AbstractListener listener = new AbstractListener() {

        @Override
        public void eventEnd() {
            // your implementation
        }

        @Override
        public boolean callMyExtraMethod() {
            //System.out.println("I am callMyExtraMethod");
            return true;
        }
    };

    listener.templateMethod();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I integrate it with my methods that receives interface type, do I need to run it every time after I passed it?

Comment: @RonTr there are 2 ways you can integrate with the methods that receive the interface type. (1) Use `AbstractListener implements InterfaceListener`. And add `template method` to the `InterfaceListener`. This way you can now pass concrete `AbstractListener` types to your methods (2) Or use your Java IDE, do a find and replace, and replace the `InterfaceListener` with `AbstractListener`, if your program design permits this.

Comment: @RonTr Was the solution helpful? If you used another solution, please post that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rename `eventEnd` to `eventEndImpl` in IDE. Then add default method:

```
public interface InterfaceListener {
    default void eventEnd() {
        if (callMyExtraMethod()) {
            eventEndImpl();
        }
    }

    void eventEndImpl();
    // Uncomment, if this method must belong to the same class. 
    // bool callMyExtraMethod();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need Java 8.